# Getting Error `TypeError: debug is not a function` while running the test cases in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch-mock

I have been getting the below error whenever i run jest `jest --coverage`;

Stackoverflow says that i can't add images to my post yet. So please open the link to view the error. Thanks

[Click here to view error's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CTS0.png)

Code and configurations are below:

---

`Package.json`

```
"fetch-mock": "^9.9.0",
 "fetch-mock-jest": "^1.5.1",
 "jest": "26.6.3",
 "@types/jest": "26.0.23",
 "babel-jest": "^27.2.0",
 "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.20.0",
 "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
```

---

`Jest Configuration`

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "./test/.*.(js|jsx)$",
  "rootDir": ".",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\.css$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "isolatedModules": true
    }
  },
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "js",
    ".",
    "node_modules"
  ]
},
```

---

`example.test.js`

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
** It shows error on above line **
import { getEntityItems } from '../../src/actions/entity1';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
global.requestURI = '';
const store = mockStore({});
const root = '/endpoint';

const testHelper = (description, path, query_params = {}) = {
    it(description, () => {
        fetchMock.getOnce(
        path, { body: { interactions: [] }, headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } }
        );
        return store.dispatch(getEntityItems(query_params)).then(() => {
            expect(fetchMock.called(path)).toBe(true);
        });
    });
};

describe('GET entites query parameters', () => {
    afterEach(fetchMock.reset());
    testHelper('accepts an array of ids', root.concat('&ids=0,1,2'), { ids: [0, 1, 2] });
});
```

Earlier the project was written in javascript and this code was running fine but now its migrated to typescript. Running tests throws the above error. I have been trying to solve this; No Luck :(

I also tried using fetch-mock-jest but couldn't get it working. If anyone can help me with the solution. It would be great! Thanks in Advance :)

---

### Debugging Update

When i tried to debug fetch-mock, to see what's happening. Got few insights.
When i click on debug at line 1, it opens `debug/index.js` as we can
see in the screenshot 1:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM0Np.png)

When i debug the test in actual using VSCode's Debugger, i saw, the value of `debug` variable present at line 1 is empty object i.e. `{}` (which is astonishing) and can be seen in the screenshot 2:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRniS.png)

I am still not able to figure it why the code isn't able to import the package content when it is actually running. :(

Comment: I think it's because you're mixing things up in your imports. If you are using typescript now then you should be using `import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';`. Give it a go and let us know if that's the solution please

Comment: @EduardoHernández Even it doesn't work. I forgot to update the `require` to `import` in the code above. Originally, the code is having import and I was trying to test it with `require` but no luck! **Updated the above code**